# cookies set in .Net read clientside in Firefox but not IE or Safari

Tags: asp.net, cookies

The following .Net settings set the cookie

```
                HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie("tw"); 
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100);
                c.Path = "/"; 
                c.Secure = false;  
                c.HttpOnly = false;
```

The following javascript reads the cookies

```
    function getCookie(c_name)
    {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name)
        {
        return unescape(y);
        }
      } 
}
```

No extra headers are sent in the request. This works in Firefox but not IE or Safari

Comment: So what happens in IE or Safari? Error?

Comment: I don't think I've ever used just javascript to get the cookies like you seem to want to. Maybe it might be easier for you to use AJAX to get the cookies from your backend instead?

Comment: I tried that before switching back. Using AJAXPro as wrapper (I only have visual web developer on the laptop) the generated javascript class for the page checking the cookies would be temperemental i.e the javascript object would just come back as undefined sometimes, when calling the cookie-checking method.

Comment: Dimitrov, the js returns 'undefined' in IE

Comment: Well it might be like it is in Chrome, you can not edit cookies on a local file, it has to be run through some sort of server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that you don't set value to your cookie. In IE, valueless cookie doesn't contain '='. This means, that in your code x is "" and y is "tw".
Then, in the if clause, the name comparison always fail, because x is an empty string. As a result, the function returns undefinied. Rewrite your logic in a way that handles the absence of '=' in a valueless cookie in IE.

Comment: this sounds reasonable. Will test and feedback. Ta